# Unable to resolve dependency tree error for running "npm i @angular/cdk" command

Tags: angular, npm

I wanted to run this command

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

and I'm getting this error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-osm@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.11.4
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.10.3" from @angular/core@10.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~10.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"10.1.6" from @angular/common@10.1.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~10.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I removed `node_modules` , ran `npm install`,`npm audit` ,`npm audit fix`and `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`  with no veil.
I also updated the "jasmine-core" to  '~3.6.0'.
Angular version: '10.1.2'
Node version: '16.13.0'
NPM version :  '8.1.4'

Here is my `package.json` file :

```json
{
  "name": "angular-osm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
     "ng": "ng",
     "start": "ng serve",
     "build": "ng build",
     "test": "ng test",
     "lint": "ng lint",
     "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
     "@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
     "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
     "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.17",
     "angular-bootstrap-md": "^12.1.0",
     "jquery": "^3.6.0",
     "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
     "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
     "tslib": "^2.0.1",
     "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
     },
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.2",
"@angular/cli": "~10.1.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.14",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.9",
"@types/node": "^14.11.2",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
"karma": "~5.2.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~9.0.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.0.3"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with different libraries. I was using a latest npm version. that was the my issue. so I had to downgrade the npm version. I installed node-v14.19.0 (npm version - 6.14.16). it works for me.